# Default expiration of Google Guava Caching

Tags: java, guava

I would like to know the default expiration policy of Guava caching. 
My need is , write once and read many times. The cache should never expire. Is this the default behavior of Guava ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about `CacheBuilder`

From the [Google docs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html)

> By default cache instances created by CacheBuilder will not perform any type of eviction.

Comment: The link is 404 error now....
**The requested URL /git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html was not found on this server. **

Comment: Fixed the link. Points now to `https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html`